# DevExpress Bar Buttons showing black and white and color when hovered?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I know it's a fat chance I'll find an answer here, but since devexpress support is a little slow I thought I'd give it a try.

Basically I'm using DevExpress 2011.1.2 beta, it's been working wonders, I love it. But I had a small issue with it recently...

I inserted an expressbar on the Delphi form and used the images from cxImageList, however, I noticed that the icons on the bar buttons were showing black and white, but when I had my mouse over, it displayed the true colors. I did not modify anything, and **yes, the button is enabled.**

Here's an image to better illustrate my problem: [image: buttons]

I know the solution must be simple, however I couldn't find anything related.

Thank you.

**EDIT**: After modifying the button's property AutoGreyScale to false the color returned, but dull and lifeless, and when mouse is over it, more colorful. [image: img2]

ImageOptions of my Bar: [image: img3]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the button's `AutoGrayScale` property to *False*. You may also want to change the value of the global `dxBarMakeInactiveImagesDingy` variable. The `TdxBarManager.Style` property may also have an effect.

Also, make sure you haven't set `HotImages` while leaving `Images` unassigned.

Comment: I edited the question with the results, which were better, but still not complete :(.

Comment: You describe the buttons as "dull and lifeless." That's a pretty good definition for *dingy*, so the `dxBarMakeInactiveImagesDingy` variable still sounds relevant.

Comment: Indeed. After changing the variable in an awkward way it worked as I wanted to. Thanks!

Comment: I wish more components had a MakeInactiveImagesDingy option.   Who needs colorful images, when you can have dingy, drab, dull lifeless ones.